# Как выполнить одновременно два условия?

Tags: c#

Я хочу выполнять код, если будет нажата кнопка, а также будет НЕ пустой textbox.
Я делаю так:

```
if (carbonFiberRadioButton2.Checked && textBox4.Text != null)
        {               
              textBox1.Text = PairConcat(Encrypt(), bina());                         
        }
```

Но почему-то выполняется только одно условие (нажатие кнопки radiobutton). С чем может быть связана ошибка?

Comment: Отладка подскажет...ставьте точку останова и вперед

Comment: Скорее всего вместо `null` нужно `""`

Comment: К сожалению ," " не работает - @ВиталийШебаниц

Comment: Ну включите отладку и все станет ясно....нужно всего то навести курсором на переменные и посмотреть что не так

Comment: Свойство `TextBox.Text` не может иметь значение `null`. В этом можно убедиться, посмотрев исходники кода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Условие при котором проверяется не содержит ли `textBox4.Text` только пробелы, или не пуста ли строка, т.е. не `null`:

```
if (carbonFiberRadioButton2.Checked && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
{               
    textBox1.Text = PairConcat(Encrypt(), bina());                         
}
```

Помимо этого, метод [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.5), позволяет не просто проверить пуста ли строка, и не пуста ли ссылка на строку, он выполняет еще одно полезное действие подобное `string.Trim()`, но имеет более высокую производительность. См. [комментарии к методу](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: Ещё наверное на Empty можно проверить

Comment: Нет никакого смысла, метод [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.5) проверяет эти оба условия.